# Why is this query returning a column name with different case?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table with a column named `roster_id` (all lower case in the table structure.) I'm trying to set a variable in my php, and the value wasn't getting set.

```
$contacts2 =  $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM roster WHERE status = 'pending'");
foreach ($contacts2 as $contact2) {
   $roster = $contact2->roster_id;
}
```

`$roster` wasn't getting set, so I did a `print_r` on `$contacts2` and this is what I got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [roster_Id] => 12
            [people_id] => 182759
            [company_id] => 1
            [first_name] => Dennis
            [last_name] => Menace
            [title] => Test Account
            [email] => esther@esthermstrom.com
            [address1] => 1105 Test Pkwy
            [address2] => 
            [city] => Chicago
            [state_id] => 13
            [country_id] => 183
            [zip] => 60613
            [phone] => 333-333-3333
            [sm] => 1
            [lu] => 1
            [status] => pending
        )

)
```

`roster_id` is being returned as `roster_Id`. Any idea why this is happening? I can get around it by just changing the php to use the alternate spelling, but if I don't know what's causing it in the first place, I won't ever feel confident that it won't suddenly change back to the correct case.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but we're using the [ezSQL](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql) database class.

Comment: No framework; just hand-coded PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If roster_Id is returned as such then it's created as such. Change it in the schema. You said "all lower case in the table structure." but didnt say how you retrieved the schema. Try a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` then use an `ALTER TABLE` to lowercase it. MySQL does not mind: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

> Column, index, and stored routine names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases.

Edit: I checked ez_sql source code for you and this is how the results are retrieved:

```
while ( $row = @mysql_fetch_object($this->result) )
{
  // Store relults as an objects within main array
  $this->last_result[$num_rows] = $row;
  $num_rows++;
}
```

It's not manipulating columns. Nor does it do any really evil tricks to your query string. No, it's a fairly simple tool and so such a problem can only come from the database.

Comment: You're absolutely right; it was created that way. My fault for having my font size set too small - the lower case i and upper case I look identical in a sans-serif font. Doh!